# Issue with connecting Google analytics add on Google sheets

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I m unabble to add on Add ons for Google analytics to run google formulas to extract data from analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

below add on is blocked on my google account, I am using powered by syncwith product but its too slow and keeps crashing. how I can Fastrack?

[https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on ]

This add on is working for my other team members but when I am trying to add to my sheets getting error.

Comment: That looks like the old one for UA.   What do you mean by blocked do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes I am getting an error message "This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.:"